# How to send data to PHP file using JQuery Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send data to php file using jQuery and ajax. However, I am only able to receive the response from ajax in json format and unable to send data.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myFile.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {ID:1}, 
        dataType:'json',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend:function(e){},
        processData: '',
        success: function(response){
            Initialize(response);   
        },
        error: function(err){alert('error')}
    });
```

Comment: url: 'myFile.php?id=1',

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Thanks Bro  ...!! :)

Comment: @AP. Isn't that what `data: {ID: 1}` does?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work, if you want to send the the value `1` to `$_GET['ID']`. Make sure the case matches, it won't work if PHP is looking for `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already done everything ok.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myFile.php',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    ID: 1,
    Test: 'Anothervalue'
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function(e) {},
  processData: '',
  success: function(response) {
    Initialize(response);
  },
  error: function(err) {
    alert('error')
  }
});
```

Using php you can get those value by

`$_GET['ID']` `$_GET['Test']`

You can send data by concating with url also

`myFile.php?ID=1&Test=Anothervalue`

But if want send data with `POST` or have much data to send you can always choose `data: {}` format to send because it's cleaner.

```
data: {
    ID: 1,
    Test: 'Anothervalue',
    // More
}
```