# Using GET in jQuery to send data to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, get

I am trying to send a row and column number of the clicked cell via GET method.

to php file, where I can check if this cell contains something or not.

For example that the URL will loke like this:

.php?c=3&r=5

I am using:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp and I have been trying to send data like it is listed on W3schools:

*Request "test.php" and send some additional data along with the request (ignore return results):*

```
$.get("test.php", { name:"Donald", town:"Ducktown" });
```

I am doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("td").click(function(event) {
var clickedBtnID = $(this).attr('id'); 
values=clickedBtnID.split('.');
var row=values[0];
var col=values[1];



$.get("info.php", {"row":row, "col":col});
```

I was looking at some other examples on StackOverFlow, like:
[How to send data to PHP file using JQuery Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649916/how-to-send-data-to-php-file-using-jquery-ajax)

I would like to say it that info.php is the diferent .php file, as the one we are working from. And another thing is that the best way to do this, would be to do it without refreshing the page. So is Ajax call the best way for this? I have tried many different things, but it seems like I can't send the data via GET method.

Comment: It's a weird question TBH as sending data in this code is one-liner.

Comment: What could be simpler than that?

Comment: @MirMasej The problem is that for some reason it doesen't work. I get the  "row" "col" value from click event. But after it seems like $.get is not working.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Maybe "simpler than that" wasn't the right phrase, I was thinking more of a: Simple solution, not ajax if possible.

Comment: you can simply make a form and in form method attribute specify the url of  php file you want to send data, put form method as get...ajax is one way of sending data used when you want to avoid full page refresh its not mandatory to use ajax only

Comment: @JakaStudent7 so it was a question: "what am I doing wrong?" in disguise. I'd advise you to open your browser's Javascript console (usually F12 -> Console) and check what appears there.

Comment: @RohitS If I use ajax, I don't have to refresh the page? I have to edit my post, that I don't want to refresh the page. Than perhaps the ajax is the right solution. I am doing this for fun and it I am just trying to learn how to use everything correctly.

Comment: @MirMasej I don't recieve any errors in the console.

Comment: @JakaStudent7 ajax calls are solely used to avoid flicker effect on your page and send and receive data (google a bit about ajax calls) and yes using it or not is your choice..you asked is there any other method than ajax rty?

Comment: and indeed @MirMasej pointed out what you are looking for..consider re framing your question or ask other question

Comment: @RohitS I have made a question a bit more clear and diferent. I was using W3schools and stackoverflow, to make it work, but it just didn't. Is the fact, that I am trying to send this data to another .php file a problem?

Comment: @JakaStudent7 - Ajax call is the right way to do this, the issue is most probably with the way you attach your event to the DOM. Please, add the relevant HTML code to the question.

Comment: @MirMasej I tried with the simple ajax call and it seemed that it solved the problem. Thank you very much all of you guys. I learned a lot from this short talk with you .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
    $.ajax({ url: 'info.php',
         data: {'row':row, 'col':col},
         type: 'GET',
         success:  {}
});
```

And it works perfectly. I don't know why the jquery $.get didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're looking to do, but I'll try to help!

Have you tried something like this? In your js file:

```
$.get("info.php?c=3&r=5");
```

Then in your PHP file:

```
//Retrieve the variables
$c = ($_GET["c"]);
$r = ($_GET["r"]);

//Then do what you need to do with $c and $r
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Trying to get values into PHP, without ajax if possible. I have tried something like that, but after I click on "cell", nothing happens with GET.